# Interaction Model isn't picking up extraneous slot values within input

Tags: json, go, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to build an Alexa skill that connects to Jira. A while back when I started The interaction model in the Alexa Skills Kit was working fine and picked up multiple slot values in one statement, even if it wasn't asked for. For example, "Open a user story in the BLAH project and assign it to Blah" would work and pick up the {ticketType}, {project}, and {assignee} slot values flawlessly. Now I've started using the Dialog.Delegate directive in ASK to allow the interaction model to figure out what it doesn't yet have and keep asking questions until all required slots are filled. Some time after I implemented this, the interaction model stopped recognizing other slot values in utterances that were intended for just one slot value to be filled. If I open the skill with a request like the above, it then asks me what the ticket type is, like I didn't already give it. I have defined sample utterances for my intent in the interaction model and all start with "Open a {TicketType}", so the fact that it still asks me for the ticket type when it's given in the input makes no sense to me.

My suspicion is that it has something to do with the way I'm returning the Dialog.Delegate directive. In my code linked below, I'm calling a function AddDialogDirective func(dialogType string, intent *Intent) which is in an open source framework I am using called alexa-skills-kit-golang. I can confirm that the Dialog.Delegate directive is actually called correctly because in the response from my lambda function I am seeing the Dialog.Delegate directive set.

```
{
    "body": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "response": {
            "directives": [
                {
                    "type": "Dialog.Delegate"
                }
            ],
            "shouldEndSession": false
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried modifying the AddDialogDirective function to be func(dialogType string, slotToIllicit *string, slotToConfirm *string, intent *Intent) instead, thinking that the framework was somehow returning empty strings in the SlotToIllicit and SlotToConfirm JSON fields instead of not returning those fields, but no luck. I was thinking that returning empty strings here might be making the interaction model that it should be illiciting only one slot at a time and ignoring the dialog model. Do you think this is the issue or could it be something completely different?

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this? I'm having the same problem.